# Parse-Partial-Sexp State at POS

Tags: sexp

What is Parse-Partial-Sexp State at POS?  Because I have been looking at some elisp code calling `syntax-ppss`.

I have the variable `ppss` being set to either `(syntax-ppss)` or to `(parse-partial-sexp last-ppss-pos delim-pos nil nil ppss)`.

Am trying to decipher the following to see what one is determining from this.

```
(or (nth 3 ppss)
    (nth 4 ppss)
    (nth 5 ppss)
```

Comment: Have looked at `36.7 Syntax Table Internals`.

Answer (score 2):

If `syntax-ppss` is what you want, then this is what you need  to do look at

```
Index entries that match ‘syntax-ppss’:

\0[index\0]
* Menu:

* syntax-ppss [Index]:                   Position Parse. (line 10)
* syntax-ppss-context [Index]:           Parser State. (line 72)
* syntax-ppss-flush-cache [Index]:       Position Parse. (line 34)
* syntax-ppss-toplevel-pos [Index]:      Parser State. (line 63)
```

which can be reached via

```
| C-h r                  | info-emacs-manual  | Help -> Read the Emacs Manual                                                 |
| u                      | Info-up            | Menu-bar -> Info -> Up                                                              |
| m elisp <return>       | Info-menu          | Info -> Menu Item -> Other...                                                 |
| I syntax-ppss <return> | Info-virtual-index | Menu-bar -> Info -> Index -> Lookup a string and display index of results...> |
```

---

If `parse-partial-sexp` is what you  want then

```
Index entries that match ‘parse-partial-sexp’:

\0[index\0]
* Menu:

* parse-partial-sexp [Index]:            Low-Level Parsing. (line 10)
```

and this can be reached via

```
| C-h f parse-partial-sexp <return> | describe-function | Help -> Describe -> Describe Function... |
| i                                 | help-goto-info    | Menu-Bar -> Help-Mode -> Goto Info       |
```

Linking to `info` node from `*Help*` buffer is a recent addition.  It works on Emacs built from the master, not sure about other versions.

---

Comment: How can I test the contents of `ppss`, which seems to be composed of an array?

Comment: `"C-h r u m e l i s p <return> i a r r a y <return> n"`